# Weird Result with gluProject()

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, 2d, glu

I have a problem with the `gluProject` Function (OpenGL).
I would like to transform a simple 3D Point from the object space into the screen space.
My code is the following:

```
int main(){
    GLdouble mvmatrix[16];
    GLdouble projmatrix[16];
    GLint viewport[4];
    GLdouble winx;
    GLdouble winy;
    GLdouble winz;
    glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, mvmatrix);
    glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projmatrix);
    glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);
    gluProject(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, mvmatrix, projmatrix, viewport, &winx, &winy, &winz);
    std::cout << winx << winy;
    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
-1.71799e+009 -1.71799e+009
```

This is a weird result and does not make sense to me. 
Does anyone know what went wrong? I did not found anything online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone know what went wrong?

You haven't created a [GL context](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Context) and made it current before using `glGetDoublev()` and `glGetIntegerv()`:

> In order for any OpenGL commands to work, a context must be current; all OpenGL commands affect the state of whichever context is current. The current context is a thread-local variable, so a single process can have several threads, each of which has its own current context. However, a single context cannot be current in multiple threads at the same time.

You can use ([Free](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/))[GLUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_Utility_Toolkit) (among [other things (not exhaustive)](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/windowtoolkits/)) to create a window & associated GL context:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // create context & make it current
    glutInit( &argc, argv );
    glutInitWindowSize( 200, 200 );
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA );
    glutCreateWindow( "GLUT" );

    GLdouble mvmatrix[16];
    GLdouble projmatrix[16];
    GLint viewport[4];
    GLdouble winx;
    GLdouble winy;
    GLdouble winz;
    glGetDoublev( GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, mvmatrix );
    glGetDoublev( GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projmatrix );
    glGetIntegerv( GL_VIEWPORT, viewport );
    gluProject
        (
        0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
        mvmatrix, projmatrix, viewport,
        &winx, &winy, &winz
        );
    std::cout << winx << " " << winy << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
100 100
```

Comment: Thanks a lot i understand now!